# Lift laminate flooring to fix squeaky floorboard

Tags: floor, subfloor, hardwood-floor, laminate-floor

I have laminate flooring installed on a mezzanine but the floorboards underneath are probably poorly nailed down and squeaking in some places. I was thinking to lift the laminate, fix them up with some flooring screws and re-apply the laminate.

The less impactful way to lift the flooring is to slide the planks by the shortest width off the mezzanine edge leaving a temporary gap in the middle of the room to access the floorboard underneath. I was wondering if that's feasible or the remaining planks will be impossible to re-apply the same way. I would start from the closest wall but the laminate is installed underneath the skirting boards.

The laminate maker is Quickstep.

[image: the planks to slide]
[image: the mezzanine edge]

Comment: Floating or glued?

Comment: Floating floor.

Answer (score 2):

Trim is probably on top of all edges.

Will probably need to start at one edge and remove piece by piece, most types of that flooring clip together at the edges of the pieces.

To make replacement easier I would mark each piece as it is removed, A-1, A-2, since a lot of pieces would have been cut to fit.

Comment: Would I be able to re-install by slide them back vertically (opposite direction of the red arrow)? My concern is that the remaining planks will expand making the space smaller.

Comment: @lcksgr   Usually the way they clip together, makes sliding them out quite difficult.  Usually need to start at one end and pull them up to unlock.  They should not expand(unless soaked in water and then it is replacement time).

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the underside of this floor? If so you may be able to install brackets from there to pull it into former contact with joists and reduce squeek.

Personally, I've found that it doesn't take long before the squeek becomes just part of the normal sound of the house and goes unnoticed.

Comment: The ceiling underneath is plastered, I think that would be a much more disruptive approach.

Comment: Ah. Valid point. There are other solutions for minimally-invasive squeek reduction; I haven't tried them so have no valid opinion on them.